# C++ create Clone of vector<Parent*> with right Child constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector, copy

What i want to do is to clone a vector of Parent* to another vector of same type. The thing is that Parent class is an interface and in the vector are only pointers to child objects.
Solutions i found:

- in clone1 i just compare the type of object and call the appropriate constructor.
- in clone2 i use something like a factory method which returns an instance of an object.

Are there some other ways to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class Parent {
public:
    virtual void printName() = 0;

    virtual Parent *clone() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    Child1() {
        printName();
    }

    void printName() override {
        std::cout << "Child1" << std::endl;
    }

    Child1* clone() override {
        return new Child1();
    }
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    Child2() {
        printName();
    }

    void printName() override {
        std::cout << "Child2" << std::endl;
    }

    Parent *clone() override {
        return new Child2();
    }
};

void clone1(std::vector<Parent *> &in, std::vector<Parent *> &out){
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        if ((dynamic_cast<Child1*>(in[i]))) {
            out.push_back(new Child1());
        }
        if ((dynamic_cast<Child2*>(in[i]))) {
            out.push_back(new Child2());
        }
    }
}

void clone2(std::vector<Parent *> &in, std::vector<Parent *> &out){
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        out.push_back(in[i]->create());
    }
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "-- Array wird erstellt" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Parent *> ar;
    ar.push_back(new Child1());
    ar.push_back(new Child2());
    ar.push_back(new Child2());
    ar.push_back(new Child1());

    std::cout << "-- Clone1" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Parent *> cp1;
    clone1(ar, cp1);

    std::cout << "-- Clone2" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Parent *> cp2;
    clone2(ar, cp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `create` is generally named `clone` and returns copy.

Comment: Missing virtual destructor (and destructor calls (that you might automatically have using smart pointers)).

Comment: `typeid(*in[i]).name(), "6Child1"` is compiler specific, so not portable. `if (dynamic_cast<Child1*>(in[i]))` is better.

Comment: Neither function actually copies the objects. Do you just want a new vector with the same structure?

Comment: You are not making a copy, you are creating new objects of the correct dynamic type. Can you extend your `Parent` interface with method `clone` mentioned before, which will return object copy?

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. You are right copy is a bit irritating, i changed this. @Jarod42 thank i also changed it to portable version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 onwards, I suggest you avoid using raw pointers, something like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Parent>>`. If you only need a shallow copy then you can just copy the vector. If you are seeking a deep copy then you can do it with a `clone()` method for each derived type:

```
for (auto& item : src)
{
    dest.push_back(item->clone()); // with raw pointers
}
```

Alternatively, you may need the [Virtual Constructor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-c-virtual-constructor/) pattern.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. You are right i should have used something like shared pointers. I think the clone method is same as what i already suggested besides that i named it create? I changed this. I dont see how the Virtual Constructor pattern can help me with this besides that the if cascade from clone1() moves to the parent constructor?

Comment: @JuliusSchellenberg Thanks for calling out my reference to the Virtual Constructor pattern. In your particular case, it is not required and mentioning it only serves to confuse you. Indeed, the [Prototype](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns/Prototype) pattern is the solution you require which was highlighted by myself and other contributors already. <pie type="[humble](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humble%20pie)" action="eaten" />